# Pandas : InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe of different shapes that I am attempting to concat.

```
df1 

price   side code              
0.7286  2   1451865675631331
0.7286  2   1451865675631400
0.7286  2   1451865675631861
0.7286  2   1451865675631866

df2 

price   side  code    col1    col2            
0.7284  2     4000000 0.7285  1000000
0.7284  2     4000000 0.7290  4000000
0.7284  2     5000000 0.7286  4000000
0.7285  2     1000000 0.7286  4000000
0.7285  2     4000000 0.7290  4000000
```

columns in `df2` are subset of `df1`. I'd like to concat `df2` with `df1` and retain columns that are in both DataFrames.

When I `concat` using:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).reindex(df1.columns, axis='columns')
```

I get `InvalidIndexError` error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Note: The data included here is mock and may not exactly replicate the error. The full tables with indices are fairly large.

Comment: use a merge instead. pandas cnocat works with unique indices; note however that your data will be duplicated

Comment: @sammywemmy can you add code for dropping columns that don't exist in both dfs and then merging?

Comment: Whats your expected result? I dont get any InvalidIndexError

Comment: @adhg I need the dfs concatenated and drop columns that aren't mutual.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
columns_to_retain = set(df1.columns).intersection(set(df2.columns))

df = pd.concat([df1[columns_to_retain], df2[columns_to_retain]], ignore_index=True)

print(df)
# Output
               code  side   price
0  1451865675631331     2  0.7286
1  1451865675631400     2  0.7286
2  1451865675631861     2  0.7286
3  1451865675631866     2  0.7286
4           4000000     2  0.7284
5           4000000     2  0.7284
6           5000000     2  0.7284
7           1000000     2  0.7285
8           4000000     2  0.7285
```

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround i do for this is to transform df to a records dict then concat them back together

**Solution** to the problem but not the most efficient

```
#to merge both 
df1 = df1.to_dict('records')
df2 = df2.to_dict('records')

#merging both dict arrays together
concat_df = df1+df2

#create a new df with result
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(concat_df)
```